# Change a report dynamically each time a user chooses a new item in DropDownMenu

Tags: c#, webforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I am trying to load `Report` dinamically whenever use choose new item in DropDownMenu. 
So far I create `Page_Load()`

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    string path = @"\Reports\";
                    CustomReportStorageWebExtension reportsStorage = new CustomReportStorageWebExtension(path);
                    ddlReportName.DataSource = reportsStorage.GetUrls();
                    ddlReportName.DataBind();

                    //Call function for populate cb
                    FillStatus();
                    FillOrgUnit();

                }
ZaposleniSaoOsig1 report1 = new ZaposleniSaoOsig1();
                GetReports(report1);
                ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(report1);

                ZaposleniSaoOsig2 report2 = new ZaposleniSaoOsig2();
                GetReports(report2);
                ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(report2);

                ZaposleniSaoOsig3 report3 = new ZaposleniSaoOsig3();
                GetReports(report3);
                ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(report3);
            }
```

Since here is problem that `ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(report3);` can load only one `Report` in `DocumentViewer`

Comment: What is a new item? Where do you decide which report to load?

Comment: This is the problem that I can not write a code to choose which report I want to load. 
Since `AspWebDocumentViewer` can only load one `report` at same time. Whatever I try I always come to same point
Since `switch()` here doesn't work as well I have no idea anymore.